# Rounding down UNIX time to lower hour in PHP

Tags: php, math, time, timezone

I have been trying in vain to round down the current time to the lower hour in PHP.

Here's what I want to do:
1. Take the current time:
`$time_now = time();`
2. Round it down to the closest hour:
`$time_now = $time_now - ($time_now % 3600);`
3. Print it using the function date:
`print date('d m Y H:i', $time_test);`

But what seems to be happening is that the printed time is what I want + 30 minutes.
e.g: If current time is 19:03, I get an output of 18:30 instead of 19:00
and if the time is 19:34, I get an output of 19:30 instead of 19:00

This driving me crazy! X(
What seems to be wrong in this code?! Something to do with the timezone perhaps? My system time is GMT +5:30

Comment: you echo $time_test but before in the code it's $time_now?

Comment: its seam to be the timezone. tested it on my local environment (GMT +2:00) and its returns full-hours

Comment: What does `date_default_timezone_get()` return?

Comment: $time_test here was a typo

My Timezone is +5:30
date('P') gives me just that. And I also think that's the culprit, becos my modulo operator returns a no which is 30*60 seconds more that what should be right.

Comment: Your problem is definitely time-zone related - useful that you're in one that spots the problem.  I guess that you should add the number of seconds implied by the minutes component of your time zone in the same expression that does the subtraction.  For the majority of the world in a timezone with an integral offset, that is a no-op (adding 0); for people in India (or Nepal, Bhutan or Newfoundland), it would make all the difference in the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `date` without printing the minutes, like:

```
print date('d m Y H') . ':00';
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you do just:

```
$now = time();
echo date('d m Y H', $now) . ':00';

// or just

echo date('d m Y H') . ':00';
```

?

It will print you current hour and fake minutes.

If you want to use that timestamp you can convert it with `strtotime` function.

```
$date = date('d m Y H') . ':00';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
```

Comment: I had initially done that, and it does work. But it seemed like a hack :P
Wanted to do it the 'proper' way...

Comment: @This is a proper way :)
Thats good enuff for me :P

Think I'll stick to just that! Wasted too much time on such a small thing already. Thanks everyone...

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is [floor](http://php.net/floor). The following works as you would like I think:

```
$time_now = floor(time() / 3600) * 3600;
print date('d-m-Y H:i', $time_now);
```

Comment: No luck, look at the example below:
16-08-2010 19:19    becomes   16-08-2010 18:30

Answer (score 0):

```
$d = strtotime($date);
$rounded = intval($d / 3600) * 3600;
$formatted_rounded = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $rounded)
```